# How to get NetBeans 7.4, Ruby and MySQL to play together (on Windows)

Tags: mysql, ruby, netbeans-7.4

The tags say it all, really. This is a project that used to work on earlier versions, but not now. If you know the answer, just stop reading and tell me how.

An existing project is working fine on older releases of [NetBeans](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NetBeans) and [MySQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MySQL). I am just trying to get it working on the latest release of everything. Nothing fancy. Just plain vanilla [Ruby on Rails](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruby_on_Rails) on Windows/MySQL.

- Clean install of Netbeans 7.4. No problems.
- Clean full install of MySQL 5.5. No problems. Includes Java connector.
- Clean install of ruby and rails from community: http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/38549. No problems.
- Everything is working just fine.
- Webrick starts and runs. Absolutely no surprises to this point.

I tried to [gem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RubyGems) install MySQL: it fails, but it is not unexpected. I have no interest in pursuing that line. Ditto for MySQL 2. It's always hard building native libraries on Windows.

I tried to gem install all/any of the following:
 * activerecord-jdbc-adapter
 * activerecord-jdbcmysql-adapter
 * jdbc-mysql

They install just fine, but the end point is always the same:

> cannot load com.mysql.jdbc.Driver.

I think I know what this means, but I have no idea how to fix it. Is it a classpath problem? Is it a bug? Is it an incompatibility just about to be fixed? Is it because I'm using Windows? Who knows? I can't think of anything else to try, and the forums are full of these errors with no solutions that seem to fit my problem.

Comment: @peter: thanks for the edit. You wouldn't have an answer too, would you?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but maybe the blog post *[Installing MySQL on Windows 7 x64 and using Ruby with it](http://blog.mmediasys.com/2011/07/07/installing-mysql-on-windows-7-x64-and-using-ruby-with-it/)* will help.

Comment: Thanks. I hadn't found that one. Unfortunately it's 2 years ago, and it's based on straight ruby, not Netbeans. That makes the gems a bit different. There are probably enough clues to find the answer to my problem, but this isn't quite it.